# PayPal Sandbox not redirecting after login attempt

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to test my WooCommerce shop with PayPal Sandbox enabled and one buyers and one sellers test account, respectively.

When I go to checkout and get asked to enter my email and password, the page is not redirecting what should be the confirmation of the payment next. The right side of the PayPal sandbox window turns blank (where the login was before).

Anyone know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly clear the cache of your browser and try it again. Try to login with sandbox account